# My Mehod on btnclick is not working, here i have given the code

Tags: asp.net, javascript, button, panel

Cant call method of Button if Button is added to panel in the .net so wt can i do?

- my code

Add Category

```
 </asp:Panel>

 <asp:Label ID="LblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="LnkBtnAddCategory_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
                              TargetControlID="LnkBtnAddCategory"
                              PopupControlID ="ModelPanel1"
                              OkControlID="BtnOKModel"
                              OnOkScript="onOK()"
                              CancelControlID="BtnCancelModel"
                                DropShadow="true"
                                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                                >
                            </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: totally not understandable what you'd like to communicate to us...

Comment: Please copy paste all your .aspx and .cs/.vb code over here, that's the only way someone can help you

Answer (score 1):

It is still quite difficult to really understand the origin of your problem or what exactly you'd like to achieve.

The `OnOkScript` property points to a JavaScript function which I suppose you understood correctly since you're mentioning JavaScript in your question post. So to achieve a postback (not ajax) you could try to do something like

```
function onOk() {            
   document.getElementById('<%=ButSave.ClientID%>').click();
   return true;
}
```

Alternatively you have to do it asynchronously. In that situation you have two possibilities

- [Page methods](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)
- [Web services](http://blog.js-development.com/2009/11/aspnet-ajax-consuming-webservice-from.html)